# Error during stored procedure select but no error in SQL select

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sybase

From the title, when I run my stored procedure, an error shows. But when I manually run the select statement that produces the error, there are no problems in SQL.

This part of the stored procedure produces an error:

"

```
  select @ls_pat_origin = pat_origin, 
         @ls_payer_tp = payer_tp 
  from ip_admission 
  where hos_cd = @as_hos_cd and 
        hrn_num = @as_hrn_num and 
        episode_num = @al_episode_num and 
        pat_tp = @as_pat_tp 

  select @err = @@error, @rc = @@rowcount 
  if (@err <> 0) 
  begin 
    rollback tran pr_oe_set_disc_ptg_tran 
    return 1  
  end 

  if ((@rc <= 0) and (@err = 0)) 
  begin 
    rollback tran pr_oe_set_disc_ptg_tran 
    raiserror 25009, 'ip_admission [pr_oe_set_disc_ptg]' 
    return 2  
  end
```

"

But when I run the select statement in SQL, no issues and a result is returned:

"

```
select *
  from ip_admission 
  where hos_cd = '62' and 
        hrn_num = '6203175322017' and 
        episode_num = 2 and 
        pat_tp = 'I'
;
```

"

I double checked the values passed to the procedure and they are the same as the one I used in the SQL select statement. And it is only happening with this one record. We use this stored procedure for other records and there is no problem for other records.

Appreciate your help.

This is the stored procedure error:

"

```
Could not execute statement.
Error occurred while selecting from ip_admission [pr_oe_set_disc_ptg].
Sybase error code=25009, SQLState="(none)"
Severity Level=16, State=1, Transaction State=0
Line 69
```

"

Comment: Error message will be very helpful in this case.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your reply. Added the error message above.

Comment: which Sybase product (ASE? SQLAnywhere? IQ? Advantage?)? If ASE ... try running your query via the `isql` command line tool to rule out issues with your client/front-end application; have the DBA check the dataserver errorlog for any associated stack traces occurring at the same time you run the query; have the DBA run `dbcc` checks (eg, tablealloc, checktable) to see if the table is corrupted

Comment: Hi @markp, I am running the procedure and the SQL statement in Sybase Interactive SQL opened from Sybase Central. Sybase Central should be ASE because I see Adaptive Server Enterprise on top of our database name. What is the ISQL command line tool and where can I open it from? Unfortunately, our team is small and do not have a DBA. We do everything ourselves. Not sure where to find the dataserver errorlog or what are stack traces or dbcc :-/

Comment: `isql` is a command line tool that should reside in the `${SYBASE}/ASE*/bin` directory; the errorlog is normally in the `${SYBASE}/ASE*/install` directory; `dbcc` is a bit more complicated for this medium (eg, you would need to get a DBA involved)

Comment: another option would be to drop/recreate the proc; objective being to eliminate the possibility of a corrupted query tree; on some rare occasions I've seen stored procs go walkabout and the only solution was to drop/recreate; before dropping the proc you'll want to make sure you grab all the associated metadata (eg, permissions, execution mode, whether the proc's marked for replication, any auditing settings, etc)